# How to use parameters in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to assign the values to a view using parameters but I'm getting the error:

> 'ALTER VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.

When using GO statement, its unable to access the variables.

How can I assign parameters to a view.

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @CA_Removal varchar(max)
SET @CA_Removal=(SELECT value FROM spider.Configuration WHERE id='Removal')
GO

ALTER view [spider3].[View] WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
select
asa.id,
ase.common,
from
[spider].Activity asa
inner join
[spider].External ase
on
asa.primaryKey = ase.owner
where
asa.type = TRY_CONVERT(int, @CA_Removal)
```

When `asa.type = 10` it works properly.

Comment: You cannot use a local variable as some sort of kludge to parameterize a view. But you don't appear to need a parameter. Just change the where clause to `where asa.type = (select value FROM spider.Configuration WHERE id='Removal');`

Comment: @Zhorov im getting error as -->Must declare the scalar variable "@CA_Removal".

Comment: @SMor in my actual code there are more than 10 parameters that needs to be inside a IN clause. Thats why i need to get through parameters

Comment: You can't use a parameter in a view. If you can't inline the 10 sub-queries (which is perfectly reasonable to do using cross apply), you need a table valued function. You need to ensure your question accurately reflects the problem you are trying to solve simplify yes, but don't oversimplify.

Comment: @Codeninja as I said above **You can't use a parameter in a view** - never - ever. The fact that you have a **`GO`** between your parameter definition and your view definition means they are in 2 completely separate batches and have no knowledge of each other.

Comment: @DaleK I tried with CTE but it do not allow to have indexes. What do you recommend to for index the view and have variables both

Comment: @codeninja it's still not clear why you want variables? As said above you can just use the sub-query. You need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: BTW note I said above table valued function - not CTE.

Comment: Check my answear  - there is a method how to use parameter in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a view.  You want a table-valued function:

```
create function spider3.udf_spider (
    @CA_Removal varchar(max)
) returns table
as return(select asa.id, ase.common
           from [spider].Activity asa join
                [spider].External ase
                on asa.primaryKey = ase.owner
           where asa.type = TRY_CONVERT(int, @CA_Removal)
          );
```

It seems really awkward to pass in a string that you just convert to an integer.  I would strongly recommend that you pass in the value as an integer:

```
create function spider3.udf_spider (
    @CA_Removal int
) returns table
as return(select asa.id, ase.common
           from [spider].Activity asa join
                [spider].External ase
                on asa.primaryKey = ase.owner
           where asa.type = @CA_Removal
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally views are not parameterized. But you could always inject some parameters. For example using session context:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE num = SESSION_CONTEXT(N'my_num');
```

Invocation:

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context 'my_num', 1; 
SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

And another:

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context 'my_num', 2; 
SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

[DbFiddleDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4511c34f568d902b6447d217792519a5)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Not me, but seems to be a hack to me, why not just use a TVF like you're supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others in the comments, **a view cannot have parameters.** Furthermore, the two batches are entirely separate, and cannot reference variables from one to the next anyway.

**You have two options:**

- Create the view with a join

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER view [spider3].[View] WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
select
  asa.id,
  ase.common,
from
  [spider].Activity asa
inner join
  [spider].External ase
  on asa.primaryKey = ase.owner
where asa.type = TRY_CONVERT(int,
    (SELECT value FROM spider.Configuration WHERE id='Removal')
);

GO
```

- Create an inline Table Valued Function

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [spider3].[iTVF]
(@typeId int)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN (

select
  asa.id,
  ase.common,
from
  [spider].Activity asa
inner join
  [spider].External ase
  on asa.primaryKey = ase.owner
where asa.type = @typeId

);

GO
```